# ¿Como hago que algunas rutas puedan verse sin autenticación en proyecto laravel 8 con jetstream?

Tags: laravel, rutas, autenticación, adminlte, laravel-jetstream

Tengo un proyecto con  Jetstream y la plantilla Adminlte. cree varias rutas para navegar pero todas me piden autenticación y deseo dejar algunas publicas y unas pocas con autenticación. Como puedo controlar eso ?

Jetstream generó esta ruta  en web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

y las mias son asi, me pide autenticación pero las quiero publcias. :

```
Route::get('productos', [HomeController::class, 'productos']);
Route::get('producto/{productoEmpresa}',[HomeController::class,'show'])->name('producto.show');
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], ¿protegiste a dichas rutas con algún middleware?

Comment: Jetstream genere middleware y protege el dashboard, pero yo hice mis rutas solo con Route::get , Route::resource etc.

Comment: Muestranos las rutas por favor

Comment: Justo estaba editando la pregunta. ahí está